# How do you display css for 'siblings' on hover but not on the item you are hovering on?

Tags: jquery, css

I have 5 bits of text and i want that when you hover over one of the texts the css bellow will be applied to all the bits of text apart from the one you are hovering over.

Could you go about doing this using jquery and the .siblings() attribute?

Html:

```
<table width="1138" height="38" border="0" class="Home111">
<tr>
<th width="146"   scope="col"> <div class="top" id="one"><a href="T-Shirts.html"class="blur out">T-SHIRTS</a></div>
</th>
<th width="146"  scope="col"> <div class="top" id="two"><a href="Bits &amp; Bobs.html"class="blur out">BLOG</a></div>
</th>
<th width="146"  scope="col"> <div class="top" id="three"><a href="Music.html"class="blur out">MUSIC</a></div>
</th>
<th width="146"  scope="col"> <div class="top" id="four"><a href="Contact.html"class="blur out">CONTACT</a></div>
</th>
<th width="146" height="38"  scope="col"> <div class="top" id="five"><a href="About.html"class="blur out"> ABOUT</a></div>
</th>
```

Css:

```
a.blur
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #339;
}

a.blur:hover, a.blur:focus
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #933;
}

.textshadow a.blur, .textshadow a.blur:hover, .textshadow a.blur:focus
{
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
outline: 0 none;
-webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
-moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}

.textshadow a.blur,
.textshadow a.blur.out:hover, .textshadow a.blur.out:focus
{
text-shadow: 0 0 4px #339;
}

.textshadow a.blur.out,
.textshadow a.blur:hover, .textshadow a.blur:focus
{
text-shadow: 0 0 0 #339;
}
```

Comment: yes .siblings() will do it but can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: `.siblings()` is not an attribute, it's a function; but yes, it will select the siblings of an item, excluding the item itself.

Comment: Now, you are only missing the JavaScript code :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can't simply use `.siblings()` because they're not strictly siblings, more like very distant cousins :) so to speed things up you should keep a list of all items in a variable and then use `.not(this)` to exclude the current item in the `hover()` callbacks.

```
var items = $('.Home111 a'); // all anchors inside table with class Home111

items.hover(function() {
    var others = items.not(this);
    // others = the siblings of current item
}, function() {
    var others = items.not(this);
    // others = the siblings of current item
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! How do go about "keeping a list of all items in a variable somewhere"

Comment: @maxmitch It's in my answer really :)

Comment: @maxmitch How about you take [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/isomeb/1/) and edit it so that I can see what you're doing wrong?

Comment: No luck! Is there a way to do this where you can be more specific and apply the css to specific 'classes' or 'Ids' on mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be specific without the HTML and not knowing which rules are supposed to be applied to the siblings

```
$('a.blur').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('someclass');
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('someclass');
});
```